# how to set image with listview in firebase android?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving data from firebase database and that is working nice but it looks awkward i want to retrive listview with images . How to do this?
Here is the code which i am using to retrieve data from firebase.

```
package com.food.sheenishere.stark;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.MenuItem;


import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class profilemain extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


    DatabaseReference mref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ListView mlistview;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
progressDialog.show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(profilemain.this, profilemain.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    Toast.makeText(profilemain.this, "hi hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    Toast.makeText(profilemain.this, "hi hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_signout:

                    Toast.makeText(profilemain.this, "You have successfully Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profilemain);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.show();

        mlistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        mlistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                arrayList.add(value);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //

                //

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    startActivity(new
                            Intent(profilemain.this, MainActivity.class));

                }
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a custom adapter with custom view. There are plenty of tutorial for this. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an image to a view i recomand you using **Glide** like this:

```
Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
    .load(profilePhotoUrl)
    .centerCrop()
    .transform(new CircleTransform(imageView.getContext()))
    .override(40,40)
    .into(imageView);
```

In which `imageView` is the object of your `ImageView`.

Don't forget to add the following line in your `dependencies` from the build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Hope it helps.